# RegExp, помощь в форматировании строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки

Как можно отформатировать строку такого типа `К У Л Ь Т У Р А    Р Е Ч И    И    Д Е Л О В О Е    О Б Щ Е Н И Е` на вот это `КУЛЬТУРА РЕЧИ И ДЕЛОВОЕ ОБЩЕНИЕ`? Пробелы рандомные, но между буквами они всегда одинаковые, а пробел между словами всегда больше чем между буквами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо произвести замену по следующему выражению на пустоту (т.е. удалить):

```
(?<=\S)\s(?=\S)|\s(?=\s)
```

пример на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3vqLM4/1)

тут мы выделяем любые пробелы перед и после которых стоят не пробелы *или* пробелы, после которых стоит пробел. К сожалению выражение рассчитано на строго один пробельный символ между буквами, если количество пробелов другое, то без предварительного вычисления длин пробелов и подстановки этих длин в выражение не обойтись. В этом случае длины можно заранее получить с помощью такого выражения [`( +)(?=.*?(\1 +))`](https://regex101.com/r/gdZ9FX/2). Первая группа захвата вернет более короткий пробел, вторая группа захвата - более длинный. Если выражение не найдет ничего, значит в строке все пробелы одной длины.

P.S. Если надо заменить строго пробелы, а не любые пробельные символы то надо заменить в выражении `\s` на собственно пробелы, а `\S` на `[^ ]`.

Comment: `\s` = `[ \f\n\r\t\v]`

Comment: @Visman Я в курсе, но решил перестраховаться, вдруг там не только сами пробелы.

Comment: Спасибо, самое короткое решение, через match нашел и просто заменил на то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Вычислить размер пробела между словами и буквами. Уникальных размеров будет - 2 (просто не ясно заранее какие они именно). Затем минимальные по размеру удалить, а максимальные заменить на 1 пробел. Регулярки тут особо не помогут. Просто найти всё по `\s+` - это будет 2 огромные кучи, но в ней будет только 2 размера.

Comment: спасибо, примерно такие мысли и были, просто я думал, можно как-то регулярками эти операции выполнять

Answer (score 1):

Сперва необходимо заменить все одиночные пробелы с последующей буквой - `\s{1}(.\S{1,})` заменяем на `$1`
А затем заменить несколько пробелов на 1 - `\s{1,}` заменяем на

На php это сперва `preg_replace("/\s{1}(.\S{1,})/i", "$1", $input);` а затем `preg_replace("/\s{1,}/i", " ", $input);`

Comment: `\s` = `[ \f\n\r\t\v]`

Comment: Дак там же может быть и не один пробел, условие такое, что пробелов сколько угодно, но равное количество